# How to send the form to e-mail?

Tags: magento-1.9

The feedback form should be sent to the mail that you specified in the admin in the module settings and to a specific template. Now the form sends data similar to the form from the page, "contact us". How to make so that sending would be on your own letter template?

> system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <general translate="label" module="feedback">
            <label>general</label>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
        </general>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <feedback_setting module="feedback" translate="label">
            <label>Feedback</label>
            <tab>general</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>9999</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <captcha translate="label">
                    <label>Captcha</label>
                    <expanded>1</expanded>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_Website>1</show_in_Website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <blocks_captcha_secret>
                            <label>Secret key</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_Website>1</show_in_Website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </blocks_captcha_secret>
                        <blocks_captcha_public>
                            <label>Public key</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_Website>1</show_in_Website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </blocks_captcha_public>
                    </fields>
                </captcha>
                <email translate="label">
                    <label>Email Options</label>
                    <expanded>1</expanded>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <recipient_email translate="label">
                            <label>Send Emails To</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <validate>validate-email required-entry</validate>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </recipient_email>
                        <email_template translate="label">
                            <label>Email Template</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </email_template>
                    </fields>
                </email>
            </groups>
        </feedback_setting>
    </sections>
</config>
```

> IndexController.php

(Here you are sending to the mail!)

Constants are pulled from the class assistant

```
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'contacts/email/recipient_email';
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER = 'contacts/email/sender_email_identity';
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'contacts/email/email_template';

    $post = array_merge($post, $data);
                            $postObject = Mage::getModel('feedback/block');
                            $postObject->setData($post);
                            $postObject->save();
                            $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                            /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
                            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                                ->setReplyTo($email)
                                ->sendTransactional(
                                    Mage::getStoreConfig($paths::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                                    Mage::getStoreConfig($paths::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                                    Mage::getStoreConfig($paths::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                                    null,
                                    array('data' => $postObject,
                                        'feedback_id' => $postObject->getId(),
                                    )
                                );
                            if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                                throw new Exception();
                            }

                            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
                            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.');
                            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                            return;

Template

    <!--@subject Feedback form@-->
    <!--@vars
    {"var data.feedback_id":"Sender Feedback id",
    {"var data.subject":"Sender Subject",
    "var data.name":"Sender Name",
    "var data.email":"Sender Email",
    "var data.phone":"Sender Phone",
    "var data.user_agent":"Sender User agent",
    "var data.remote_ip":"Sender Remote ip",
    "var data.created_at":"Sender Created at",
    "var data.message":"Message"}
    @-->
    Feedback id: {{var data.feedback_id}}<br>
    Subject: {{var data.subject}}<br>
    Name: {{var data.name}}<br>
    Email: {{var data.email}}<br>
    Telephone: {{var data.phone}}<br>
    User agent: {{var data.user_agent}}<br>
    Remote ip: {{var data.remote_ip}}<br>
    Created at: {{var data.created_at}}<br>

    Message: {{var data.message}}
```

> config.xml

```
<email>
                <custom_template>
                    <label>Feedback template</label>
                    <file>feedback_form.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </custom_template>
            </email>
```

What needs to be changed to apply my module settings, rather than settings from the "contacts" block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the const variable as currently its taking contact email setting as place of feedback section configuration setting

so change below code

```
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'contacts/email/recipient_email'; 
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER = 'contacts/email/sender_email_identity'; 
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'contacts/email/email_template';
```

with below code

```
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'feedback_setting/email/recipient_email'; 
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER = 'feedback_setting/email/sender_email_identity'; 
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'feedback_setting/email/email_template';
```